# Conteúdo inseguro, JS audio

Tags: javascript

Estou finalizando um JavaScript e falta apenas a execução de um áudio quando determinado evento ocorrer. Estou testando o seguinte código:

```
console.log('sobre audio');
        var a = new Audio("https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/2587/AudioTest%20%281%29.ogg");
      a.play();
```

O código acima funciona, porém quando eu altero o link para um link de áudio da minha escolha ele gera o seguinte erro no console(em negrito, o link que foi substituído):

> Carregando conteúdo misto (inseguro) "**http://www.picosong.com/6b4L/#**" em uma página segura[Saiba mais] game.php
>   GET 
>   http://www.picosong.com/6b4L/#

Apesar de informar que está carregando, o conteúdo nunca é carregado, provavelmente por que foi alertado como inseguro.

Qual domínio eu posso carregar esse arquivo de forma direta para que meu navegador(Mozilla) o reconheça e o execute? Ou o problema não é este?

Comment: Aqui o audio carregou no Firefox e no Google Chrome, mesmo usando o protocolo `file:///` e `http://` na url do `localhost`. No googlechorme ocorre o mesmo problema pra ti?

Comment: Não tenho o Chrome aqui :/ Você testou com este link? "http://www.picosong.com/6b4L/#"

Comment: Sim testei, essa página é sua? Então lá funcionou normal, tinha uma musica de Rap, mas não tinha nada do `https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/2587/AudioTest%20%281%29.ogg` lá. Testei a musica de rap e funcionou no Firefox e Chrome.

Comment: Então, esse link do mozillademos eu peguei, juntamente com esse código, num site do Mozilla sobre áudio. A única coisa que deveria ser feita ao meu ver era substituir esse link do Mozilla por um outro de áudio direto, porém o link de rap que te passei não é reproduzido aqui :/

Comment: Mas em que página você injetou esse código? O site picosong então não é seu? Como você injetou o código no site picosong?

Comment: Não, eu estou usando o scratchpad do Mozilla(shift+ F4) para executar uma função num determinado site, para detectar uma mudança num elemento x. Caso esse elemento x seja alterado em algum momento, será executado esse script do som.

Comment: picosong não é meu não haha, achei no google agora a pouco e upei o rap lá para fazer um teste. Quando eu solucionar esse problema, upo uma música mais adequada kk

Comment: Com scratchpad funcionou normal, é Linux ou Windows? Ao menos no Windows funcionou.

Comment: Amigo posso ser sincero, acho que você esta me enrolando, eu li no corpo da tua pergunta o termo "game.php", isto da a entender que você executou o código em uma página php e não no picosong, se este game.php for uma página sua, então o problema pode ser ae (ou no seu Apache). Se não der detalhes fica muito dificil ajudar.

Comment: Estou usando na página https://us21.tribalwars.us/game.php?village=5044&screen=market&mode=exchange  , é de lá que vêm o game.php. Como eu disse, estou monitorando um campo desta página, quando ele sofre alteração(provinda do servidor, que atualiza o campo a cada y segundos), o som é tocado. Estou usando Windows sim.

Comment: entendo, parece que o problema não é bem com o teu Firefox então.

Comment: Segue o código que estou utilizando no scratchpad: 

var target = document.querySelector('div.premium-exchange-sep');
var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
    if (target.innerHTML >= '500') {
console.log('sobre audio');
var a = new Audio("http://www.picosong.com/6b4L/");
a.play();
observer.disconnect();
    }
  });
});
var config = {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  characterData: true
};
observer.observe(target, config);

Comment: `picosong.com/6b4L/` não é um arquivo de áudio é uma página html, nunca que você vai conseguir executar assim: `new Audio("picosong.com/6b4L/"); a.play();` e não vejo o que `MutationObserver` tem haver com https://us21.tribalwars.us/game.php?village=5044&screen=market&mode=exchange - Amigo posso ser sincero, acho que é alguma confusão sua.

Comment: Entendo, pensei que ambos os links funcionassem pelo mesmo princípio, visto que o do Mozilla funcionou. Tem alguma alternativa para eu usar um áudio meu, seja através de link (onde upar?) ou lendo um arquivo .mp3 diretamente do meu sistema?

Comment: Não sei se vai funcionar, mas clique em download, vai gerar um link, copie o link e use com `new Audio`, o link deve ficar algo como: `new Audio('http://picosong.com/cdn/94d52b94c03237d18c72c400e7b7e284.mp3')`

Comment: Tão simples, vlw pela paciência e emprenho, problema resolvido :)